# SQL Join - displaying table, even if second joined table has no relevence

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one with persons and the other with various dogs that each person owns. I would like to only query the database once.

I would like to always display the active people, even if they don't have any dogs attached to their id. How would I query this?

```
SELECT person.*, dog.* 
FROM person 
LEFT OUTER JOIN dog ON person.id = dog.person_id AND 
WHERE person.active=true and dog.active=true
```

Comment: This query does not work due to the extra `AND` in the join. Which is also the answer to your problem.... :)

Comment: Is it an extra `AND` before the `WHERE`, or a `WHERE` in the `ON` clause? There are important distinctions to be understood...

Answer (score 4):

Move the condition to the join (`on` clause); that way you will left join any records that match both the `person_id` and the `active` flag. If no active `dog` is found, the `person` is still present in the result.

If you add the condition in the `where` clause, first the left join is evaluated, and then all records that are not active dogs (*including those that don't have a dog at all*) are filtered out. It effectively turns your `left join` into an `inner join` if you do that.

```
SELECT 
  person.*, 
  dog.* 
FROM 
  person 
  LEFT JOIN dog ON person.id = dog.person_id AND dog.active=true
WHERE 
  person.active=true
```

Comment: How does moving it change the output of the query

Comment: Because you will left join any records that match both the person_id and the active flag. If no dog is found, the person is still present in the result. If you add the condition in the `where` clause, first the left join is evaluated, and then all records that are not active dogs (including those that don't have a dog at all) are filtered out. It effectively turns your left join into an inner join if you do that.

Comment: @SabashanRagavan Because in an `OUTER JOIN` (a.k.a. `LEFT JOIN` / `RIGHT JOIN`) the `ON` clause filters *which rows of the joined table will be used* whereas the `WHERE` clause filters *the final result set*. So a condition in the `WHERE` clauses removes people with no dogs because it doesn't match; in the `ON` clause, it just removes the dogs and leaves the people.

Comment: @GolezTrol A good example of why answers should include a full explanation of the solution rather than just fixed code. :) (That was in response to your great explanation, not about the downvote, BTW. Simulpost. (Although seeing Sabashan's next comment, I guess it was about the downvote after all, in a way!))

Comment: @IMSoP You're actually right about that, but I felt I've personally answered this question at least 5 times on SO before. Maybe I should have spent time on either finding a duplicate or providing more context, but I hoped the code would be self-explanatory. But you're right. I'll do better next time. ;)